# Store FullCalendar state in URL

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to configure FullCalendar to store its state in the URL? I would like to be able to return users to their previous calendar state when they perform an action that takes them away from the calendar temporarily.

Comment: you can use localStorage object for storing data on client.

Comment: True, but that doesn't allow for things like bookmarking or sharing. I'd rather use the URL for this data so that it doesn't depend on local data storage.